# PGError: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

```
//select query
    SELECT 
           H.id, 
           H.case_type, 
           H.case_number,
           H.status        
    FROM tblentrymaster H
    JOIN (
      SELECT hs.id, hs.case_id, MAX(hs.originol_page) MaxScoreByGameUser
      FROM tbl_file hs
      GROUP BY hs.id, hs.case_id) as tblm
       ON hs.case_id = H.id
    WHERE H.status='1'
```

Comment: What are the leading `//` for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure, but you set the alias `tblm` for the result table and try to get its ID with `hs.case_id` afterwards, which is unknown, I assume.

So just try `tblm.case_id` instead of `hs.case_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't joining on `hs`, you're joining on `tblm`, and the `on` clause should represent that:

```
SELECT 
       H.id, 
       H.case_type, 
       H.case_number,
       H.status        
FROM tblentrymaster H
JOIN (
  SELECT   hs.id AS id, 
           hs.case_id AS case_id, 
           MAX(hs.originol_page) MaxScoreByGameUser
  FROM     tbl_file hs
  GROUP BY hs.id, hs.case_id) as tblm
ON tblm.case_id = H.id -- Here
WHERE H.status='1'
```

Comment: @ChaudharyDevDagar Only **after** you perform the join, not beforehand.

Comment: @ChaudharyDevDagar just add it to the select list

Comment: sorry to disturb u again but i m very new to it.. just a begginer.

i am facing the same problem again and again.
i wanted to fetch
id, case_type, case_year and status from tblentrymaster(first table) and case_id and maximum of page number(field name is origional_page) from tbl_file(second table)..

will u please elaborate it 
:(

Comment: @ChaudharyDevDagar it's impossible to follow a question posted this way. Please post a new question and describe **exactly** what you're trying to achieve.